# sys_exec() MySQL event not firing in Windows 7

Tags: mysql

I've got sys_exec running on Windows on my little test server and confirmed that I can execute commands by running `SELECT sys_exec('dir > c:\\tst\\out.txt') FROM dual` and verifying the out.txt is created.  So I thought I'd be able to create a trigger to run this.  I used the following:

```
CREATE EVENT testevent
 ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 second
DO 
    SELECT sys_exec('dir > c:\\tst\\out.txt') FROM dual
```

Which is the same syntax I used and could see the event being fired.  However the sys_exec one won't - the file is never created.

I am a bit new to this, but can't see anything wrong with the sql.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Hi, not sure what  you mean with the URL - I can run sys_exec from mysql with no issue, I can run events with no issues, but I can't combine the two..?

Comment: Not sure why it did not work. Did you also try moving this `select sys_exec(....` statement to another SP and call that SP in event?

Comment: Not yet - I can still see the event in the show events() query, if the event can't be fired does mysql record why?

Comment: I've had another look at this.  Turned on the general log to see if that would give me any indications of why the event isn't triggering, but it doesn't.  I've also created a basic table called dual with 2 columns, an Auto-increment id and a varchar.  I've changed the event to be : 
 INSERT INTO test.dual VALUES (NULL,"2");` and can see this appear in the log, but nothing is triggered.  The log makes it look like its trying the event, but failing - is there some other logging I can turn on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working.  Turns out the cause was something really, really simple.  The scheduler isn't enabled by default.  So running **SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON** and recreating an event worked.

Thanks to all who tried to help.